# The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed

Tags: xml, dtd

I have this xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "plantdtd.dtd">
<catalog>
<title>Flowers of the week</title>
<plant id="A1">
    <name>Aloe vera</name>
    <climate>tropical</climate>
    <height>60-100cm</height>
    <usage>medicinal</usage>
    <image>aloevera.jpg</image>
</plant>
<plant id="A2">
    <name>Orchidaceae</name>
    <height>8-12in</height>
    <usage>medicinal</usage>
    <usage>decoration</usage>
    <image>Orchidaceae.jpg</image>
</plant>
</catalog>
```

I wrote a DTD like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "file:/home/p10398/plantdtd.dtd"
[
<!ELEMENT catalog(title,plant+)>
<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT plant(name,climate,height,usage,image)+>
<!ELEMENT name(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT climate(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT height(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT usage(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image(#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Iam getting this error:

Fatal error:                                                                    
   Public ID: null                                                              
   System ID: file:/home/p14524/plantdtd.dtd                                    
   Line number: 4                                                               
   Column number: 3                                                             
   Message: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
 declaration must be well-formed.

Can someone explain whay Iam getting this error? or the correct DTD?

EDITS and UPDATES:
Ah! Thanks Daniel.
Now the previous error is gone.
 My new DTD is

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (title,plant+)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT plant (name,climate,height,usage,image)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT climate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT height (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT usage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST plant id ID #REQUIRED>
```

Iam getting this new error:

Line number: 18                                                              
   Column number: 9                                                             
   Message: The content of element type "plant" must match "(name,climate,height,usage,image)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `DOCTYPE` from the DTD. You should also have spaces after the element names in the declarations.

**New DTD**

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (title,plant+)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT plant (name,climate,height,usage,image)+>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT climate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT height (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT usage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
```

Now that the DTD is valid, you will see a few errors when validating your XML.

The first is that you need to declare the `id` attribute of the `plant` element. I'd suggest `<!ATTLIST plant id ID #REQUIRED>`.

The second is that `climate` is missing from the second `plant`. I'm not sure if that's an XML error or a DTD error. The element declaration for `plant` doesn't make a whole lot of sense though because it's those 5 elements in that order one or more times. If you need help with that piece, describe what `plant` should contain and I can help you write the right declaration.

Comment: Can you please check the latest update of my question and answer back.

Comment: @RaviRishie - That error is what I was talking about in the last paragraph of my answer. Your second `plant` doesn't match `(name,climate,height,usage,image)` because it doesn't have a `climate` element. Is that element supposed to be optional? I also see it now has two `usage` elements. Maybe you'd rather use `<!ELEMENT plant (name,climate?,height?,usage*,image*)>` or something?

Comment: Thanks dude! Its working fine by mentioning the occurences here

Comment: @RaviRishie - Awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: Please check this one too 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344663/exception-cvc-complex-type-2-4-a-invalid-content-was-found-starting-with-eleme

Answer (score 2):

"the markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well formed" error

in my case i was behind a proxy so i guess it was causing issues

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

so i changed it to https

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. But in my case it got resolved like this. Read the whole derscription here

The error i was encountering suggests that there's an issue with the way of my XML payload. In XML, certain characters and structures have specific rules, and any deviation from these rules can result in parsing errors.

In myprovided payload:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [<! ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://169.254.169.254/" >]>
<stockCheck>
    <productId>
        &xxe;
    </productId>
    <storeId>2</storeId>
</stockCheck>
```

*there's a space between `<!` and `ENTITY`, which might be causing the parsing error. Try removing the space to make it `<!ENTITY`*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://169.254.169.254/" >]>
<stockCheck>
    <productId>
        &xxe;
    </productId>
    <storeId>2</storeId>
</stockCheck>
```

**If the issue persists, consider ensuring that your XML payload adheres to the XML syntax rules. Also, verify that there are no extra spaces, invalid characters, or unclosed tags that might be causing parsing errors.**