# Exception: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with eleme nt 'employee'. One of '{contractemployee}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

So ..I have this ER diagram:
[image: ER diagram]

Hence I wrote an company.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<company xmlns="urn:company.Namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="urn:company.Namespace companyxsd.xsd">
    <companyname>ABC company</companyname>
    <address>xyz street, India.</address>

    <department>
        <dname>Marketing</dname>
        <deptphoneno>9876543210</deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno>0442456879</deptfaxno>
        <deptemail>marketing@abc.com</deptemail>

        <employee>
            <empid>101</empid>
            <ename>Rishie</ename>
            <emailid>rishie@abc.com</emailid>
            <phoneno>9876543211</phoneno>
        </employee>

        <contractemployee>
            <name>Ravi</name>
            <phoneno>9874563214</phoneno>
        </contractemployee>
    </department>

</company>
```

and my companyxsd.xsd as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:company.Namespace" xmlns="urn:company.Namespace">

    <xs:element name="company">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>

       <xs:element name="department">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
          <xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:integer"/>
          <xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"/>

          <xs:element name="employee">      
           <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="empid" type="xs:integer"/>
             <xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>


          <xs:element name="contractemployee">      
           <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>

         </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I am not sure whether my xml represents the ER diagram as it is. If not please help me out with the correct xml template.

Since Iam a beginner..I have doubts on the XSd I have written. ':(

For the above, I keep getting errors as such

```
Exception: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with eleme
nt 'employee'. One of '{contractemployee}' is expected.
```

The new error:

```
Exception: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'company'.
```

Help me out here pals!

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same two errors.  The error does not require any changes in the linking part of the `xml` and `xsd` file.  Actually, the scorm editor can be very tricky.

**one of {employee,contractemployee} is expected**

This error expects some of the attributes in the element contract employee and employee such minOccurs and MaxOccurs attributes.

I have posted the appropriate code for the `xml` and `xsd` that runs successfully in the scorm editor. HAPPY CODING !!!

XML :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <companyname>company name</companyname>
    <address>address</address>
    <department>
        <dname>dname</dname>
        <deptphoneno>22238500</deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno>123456789</deptfaxno>
        <deptemail>email@email</deptemail>
        <employee>
            <empid>123</empid>
            <ename>ename</ename>
            <emailid>email@email</emailid>
            <phoneno>9444872829</phoneno>
        </employee>
        <contractemployee>
            <name>name</name>
            <phoneno>9445815259</phoneno>
        </contractemployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

XSD :

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="company">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="department">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="employee">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="empid" type="xs:integer"/>
                                        <xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="contractemployee">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Glad to have you apart of the community!
Please be sure to checkout our help section
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.

Answer (score 0):

The XML + XSD you posted do not create the error you mentioned, the XML is not actually valid xml. However you are very close, there is a problem with your namespace declaration in the XML and also in the XSD.

In the XSD you need to set the target namespace, like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="company.namespace">
```

Now to make sure the document validates, the namespace in the xml needs to be the same as the one you put in the XSD. In the XML the formatting of the namespace declaration is also invalid. Make it as follows:

```
<company xmlns="company.namespace">
```

Keep in mind this is just a namespace, it is not an actual reference to the xsd file, a lot of namespaces look like URI's, however most are not actual functional URI's either.

I replaced the namespace with an example "company.namespace" just to make it clearer. Using filenames might create the suggestion they actually point to files.

When using the schemaLocation in the XML to identify the corresponding XSD file you need to add the namespace/prefix declaration. Currently the xml parser does not recognise the xs prefix because it is unknown in the XML file. You can solve this as follows:

```
<company xmlns="urn:company.Namespace"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xs:schemaLocation="urn:company.Namespace companyxsd.xsd">
```

Here are the resulting files:
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<company xmlns="urn:company.Namespace"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xs:schemaLocation="urn:company.Namespace companyxsd.xsd">    <companyname>ABC company</companyname>
    <address>xyz street, India.</address>

    <department>
        <dname>Marketing</dname>
        <deptphoneno>9876543210</deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno>0442456879</deptfaxno>
        <deptemail>marketing@abc.com</deptemail>

        <employee>
            <empid>101</empid>
            <ename>Rishie</ename>
            <emailid>rishie@abc.com</emailid>
            <phoneno>9876543211</phoneno>
        </employee>

        <contractemployee>
            <name>Ravi</name>
            <phoneno>9874563214</phoneno>
        </contractemployee>
    </department>

</company>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:company.Namespace" xmlns="urn:company.Namespace">

    <xs:element name="company">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>

       <xs:element name="department">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
          <xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:integer"/>
          <xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"/>

          <xs:element name="employee">      
           <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="empid" type="xs:integer"/>
             <xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>


          <xs:element name="contractemployee">      
           <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>

         </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: So... I am using company.xml and companyxsd.xsd ... So.. I tried what u said and its throwing some other error now! I have updated my question . please check it.

Comment: You have added a  xs:schemaLocation attribute in your XML file, this is incorrect. It has a namespace prefix 'xs' that is not declared and therefore unknown in the XML.

Comment: so..what should I do? can you elaborate it? @ophychius

Comment: elaborated in the answer

Comment: A new error now:
`Exception: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'company'.`

Comment: The code from your question does not give that same Exception when validating, so you might have slightly different code that your are trying to run. I have added the completed code.

Comment: NOPE..same error showing up! I am editng my question with the current code I have(I cross checked..its the same as u have shown). If its possible..is it okay to write without the whole schema blah blah?

Comment: Ravi, I am not sure what is going on. I used your files and stuck them in an online validator as well as eclipse. It validates in both, what do you use to validate.

Comment: It's something called a scorm editor..is there any other way to code it?

Comment: I fear the problem you face now might be elsewhere in your project. Maybe the path to the XSD file, or maybe the editor does not deal well with the XSD file linked from the XML.  Maybe try a different tool to build / validate. Or maybe it is a scorm specific issue