# how to disable xml validation in tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I'm deploying a war-package to tomcat in a local network, and it just failed with below error
[image]

To my understanding, it's trying to download `dtd` to validate xml file, but it is been redirected to a auth web page due to limit network access.

so my question is how to avoid such error in a local network, does `disable xml validation` is a good method in this situation? if so, how?

Comment: Is there a space or line before that xml tag. Try deleting all chats before xml tag.

Comment: thanks @surya , but I think it's network error not validation error

Comment: Which DTD is being validated here?

Comment: it's https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd

Comment: well you can have that dtd in your machine and use it locally..  look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333939/the-markup-declarations-contained-or-pointed-to-by-the-document-type-declaration